# Using LED lamp in kitchen range hood

Tags: led, hood, halogen

I have a Whirlpool UXT5536AAS household range hood. The [owner's manual](https://www.whirlpool.com/content/dam/global/documents/201510/owners-manual-W10274302-UC-RevF.pdf) states it uses 120V, 40W maximum halogen lamps made for a G9 base. The hood does not have any controls for dimming the lamps and the wiring diagram on page 12 does not seem to show any transformers etc, so I believe there's no low voltage involvement.

Is there any reason those halogen lamps cannot be replaced with LED bulbs with a G9 base? Are there concerns about heat from the stove below that mandate or dictate the use of traditional halogen lamps?

Comment: The electronic drivers in the base for the LED does not like heat.  The base usually produces some heat and if not in the right type of fixture that has some ventilation will tend to burn out faster.  Not sure if halogen bulbs are needed or if that is only the maximum.

Comment: @crip659 - so does that mean it would be reasonable to experiment with the swap (and hold on to the original halogens) and see if it burns up "unreasonably soon"? Worst case, I would have to revert to the originals, but maybe I get lucky that the LED survives?

Comment: does the hood, with lights off, get too hot to touch after boiling a pot of pasta or whatever you do that makes it the hottest? if you can still touch it or even almost stand to touch it, it's fine for LEDs.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis. I don't believe I've actually ever tried this test, but will give it a shot. For now, my challenge will be to locate a small enough LED bulb that will fit in the small space. The old bulb is pretty compact at only 1.5" long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key issue is heat. A 40W halogen produces a lot of heat. An equivalent LED will be around 4W - so 10% as much power and on the order of 10% as much heat. However, halogen bulbs *love* heat, LEDs do not, so an LED bulb may have more issues with heat dissipation than a halogen bulb, even though there is a lot less heat to dissipate. This is especially a concern with a bulb in a small enclosed space, as is typically the case for these tiny halogen bulbs.

There is a secondary problem with heat. A range hood is not nearly as bad as inside an oven, but it can still get hot. Again, halogens work well with that heat (even inside an oven!) and LEDs do not. That being said, many newer range hoods come with LED lighting built in, so obviously this is not an insurmountable problem. But with a built in fixture the driver circuitry can be placed away from the hottest area of the appliance. With a plug-in or screw-in bulb, that is not an option.

Bottom line: For around $5 (maybe less) you can get a bulb and try it. If it works, great! If not, switch back to halogens. If you have multiple bulbs in the fixture near each other, switch them all at the same time - otherwise a hot halogen could mess up an otherwise OK LED.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a shot and hope that it works. If not, I still have the original halogens anyway, so I can revert.

Comment: FYI, a bit of a guessing game as to exactly which LEDs to use. But basically size/base (G9) + "equivalent to 40W". In one place I found a halogen 40W listed as 600 lumens. But the LEDs that claim to be 40W equivalent (actual power 3W - 5W) are in the 400 - 470 lumen range. So depending on the specifics, you may find the replacement not quite as bright as the original.